# PHP :: MVC All Controller requests through Model?

Tags: php, model-view-controller

Is it best practice to have all information pass through the MODEL to the CONTROLLER?

For example, I have a controller named "Apps" and a model named "App".  I want to show a form with a list of users, which is in the "Users" class in the libraries folder.  Can I simply request the list of users from the "Users" class directly from the CONTROLLER or is it best to first go through the MODEL and then to the CONTROLLER?

TIA

Comment: Controllers are not supposed to pull information from the Model layer. Their responsibility is to alter the state of said layer. The view classes are the ones, that are responsible for gathering the current (or changed) state from the Model layer and populating templates with it.

Answer (score -1):

The way MVC normally works, is that the View makes a request to the Controller. The Controller then accesses the Model, handles all the business logic and updates the View.

So in your case, the User class could be your Model.

Eg.

- The View requests a list of users
- The Controller handles the request and gets the list of users from the Model (eg. through database)
- The Controller then updates the View with the list or the View has access to the list and renders it.

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) is more information.

Answer (score -1):

As you tag your question with `php` I can explain in its terms. View(HTML form or AJAX) do request to controller, usually a php file(by post or get request) what processes and redirects requests to (Model)separate php code what work with data(DB), that code returns result to controller and it one to model. Consider using some existing MVC framework what suits your needs.

> Model–view–controller is an architectural pattern commonly used for
>   developing user interfaces that divides an application into **three**
>   interconnected parts. This is done to separate internal
>   representations of information from the ways information is presented
>   to and accepted from the user. The MVC design pattern decouples these
>   major components allowing for efficient code reuse and parallel
>   development.
>   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller

Answer (score -1):

I'm agree your point, but we must consider the size of the project. For example, in one big-size project, I usually command it like controller <=> services <=> models <=> tables.

- Tables: run sql (CURD)
- Models: call tables finish one feature (Like after get article also need update view times)
- Services: call models finish one function (Like payment)
- Controllers: Input/Permissions validator then call service finish it.

Of course, if one simple blog we can do all in controllers.

And same idea for view, may full page, may group components as one page, and component may also has childrens.